# Export all Azure groups and owners

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to export every group within my organisation and their owner(s) if possible
Also to return no owner or remain blank if no owner is assigned

I am new to azure powershelgl so am starting from zero here

I have looked through numerous other threads but don't seem to find any that returns owners owners only group members. I don't necessarily need the membership of these groups just the name of the group, the owners and export this to CSV

Thank you for any assistance

I haven't really tried anything as I am very new to azure powershell and also unable to find anything online

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below***:

To import the list of Azure AD Groups and its owners, use the below Powershell Script:

```
connect-AzureAD
$groups = Get-AzureADGroup -All $true
$result = foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Get-AzureADGroupOwner -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true | ForEach-Object {
            [PsCustomObject]@{
            'Group'     = $group.DisplayName
            'Owner'  = $_.UserPrincipalName
        }
    }
} 
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\users\testkhann.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

**The Csv File imported successfully like below:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, it does appear to work for me also.
I think the issue i have now is due to having over 170k groups and thus timing the powershell script out